# ng-repeat sorting one column with two, exclusive JSON variables

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a JSON with two variables User and First_User. First_User is only interesting if there is no User (who will appear over time).

I create a Table with ng-repeat and succeed to amend my JSON: if a User appears, First_User is deleted. So I have always only one of them.

But if I want to sort now (as seen below) it doesn't work,

Code excerpt:

```
<th> <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'User'; sortReverse = !sortReverse"> User </a> </th>
...
<tr ng-repeat="roll in JSON </tr>
<td>{{ roll.User}} {{ roll.First_User }}</td>
```

JSON example:

```
[{ "User" : "", "First_User" : "Horace" }, { "User" : "Donald", "First_User" : "" }, { "User" : "", "First_User" : "Donald" }, { "User" : "Donald", "First_User" : "" }]
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

you should manipulate the JSON obj to have only one column to sort. For example copying the `First_User` data to the field `User`